# when i try to include a php include function in a php page and runs it is showing that command as it is.. not fetching any contents

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, include, require

when the code is run  it is displayed that
It is not displaying any contents of header.php

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">                    

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>ADMIN PANEL</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"     type="text/css">



    </head>

    <?php require("header.php"); ?>

    <!-- -->
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="row">




            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Blank</h1>
            </div>

            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->



    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

The contents of the require files are not shown
i tried require,include and all.

What is the problem with this...
It works fine if the contents of the header.php is pasted in the given section.. but it doesn't work when include or require commands are called

My header.php is as following

```
            echo'
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                 <li><a href="itsupport.html">SUPPORT</a></li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">PRODUCTS AND SERVICES <span class="caret"></span></a>

             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="itservices.html">IT SERVICES</a></li>
                 <li><a href="voiceservices.html">VOICE SERVICES</a></li>
                 <li><a href="itservices.html">INFRASTRUCTURE</a></li>
                 <li><a href="webservices.html">WEB & GRAPHICS DESIGN</a></li>
                 <li class="divider"></li>

             </ul>


          </li>
          <li><a href="careers.html">CAREERS</a></li>
          <li><a href="careers.html">INTERESTING INFORMATION</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>';


          ?>
```

Comment: where is your PHP code?

Comment: Any error being displayed ? Are you sure of the path to 'header.php' ? What is the content of header.php ?

Comment: Both files are in the same directory?

Comment: Provide us with header.php and the url scheme.

Comment: It is a browser error with chrome.. it works fine in firefox.. i tried it also in a hosting server and is working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution.. The code is perfect it is a problem with my chrome browser.. Whatever code i run it adds a  tag before the php tags .. I changed the browser and works fine...

Thank you for your valuable support...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the file where you try to include your header.php is also a `.php` file, not `.html` or `.htm`? That's because html-files usually don't don't get checked for anything that needs to be processed by PHP - so there will be no PHP output.

Comment: header.php... guess so

Comment: He includes `header.php`, but hasn't told us so far which file extension the file has where he tries to include it (the file which contains the code he showed us).

Comment: @RichardBernards what JoelP is trying to say if the extension of the file where header.php is included is .php not .html or .htm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have PHP on your server.

make a file called 'phpinfo.html' with this content:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Put this file on your server. Then when you load this file, from your server, in your browser you should see a lot of information about PHP, not just the content.

After that check whether your PHP is used with the .php extension. Simply rename the file to 'phpinfo.php' and try again. If the first works, and this doesn't, then you have to make your server use the .php extension for PHP files. How that's done depends on your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved index file with .php extension, for example index.php